# Unable to get value of constant in angularjs service

Tags: angularjs

In my module i added constant like below

```
var app = angular.module("myapp", ["ngRoute"]).constant("myConfig", {
"url": "http://localhost",
"port": "80"
});
```

I was trying to get value of constant in my service like below but i am not able to get anything.

```
app.service('MyService', function MyService($http, myConfig) {

}
```

What is correct way to get value of constant in service?

Comment: `myConfig` is undefined or are you getting some error? I've made a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/The_Bear/jg0mmaqr/3/) and I hadn't any problem injecting the constant into a service...

Comment: @The.Bear i didnt passed myConfig in controller. So you are passing myConfig to controller and then controller passes forward. Is that the only way or if any more better ways?

Comment: There are three ways to inject the constant in a service:  Inline Array Annotation, `$inject` Property Annotation, and Implicit Annotation. Which is better is a matter of opinion. See [AngularJS Developer Guide - Dependency Injection Annotation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#dependency-annotation)

Comment: $inject seems to be the best way of injection

Answer (score 2):

you can either create service function and return the constant value through service function. Or simply you can just inject the constant to controller and directly call the constant value.

```js
var app = angular.module("myapp", []);

app.constant("myConfig", {
"url": "http://localhost",
"port": "80"
}); 

app.service('MyService', function MyService($http, myConfig) {
  var vm = this;
  
  vm.getConst = function(){
      return myConfig.url;
  }
});
app.controller("ctrl",function($scope,MyService,myConfig){
  //get it throuth servive
 
  console.log(MyService.getConst());
  
  //get it from controller 
  
  console.log(myConfig.url);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="ctrl">

</div>
```

Comment: Since the `getConst` function omits a `return` statement, the function returns the [primitive value `undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined).

Comment: @georgeawg what do u mean by omits return. i update it and `getConst` return the value